# Ubuntu 21.04. 2 apps no longer working, uninstall and reinstall doesn’t fix

Tags: software-uninstall

Ubuntu 21.04. Two of my apps are no longer working. VLC and Flameshot stopped working. I uninstalled, rebooted and reinstalled them multiple times using the ‘Ubuntu Software’ app. It says they’re both installed but when I double click on their icons, nothing happens. I also installed using the terminal (sudo apt-get install vlc). It installed but when I click on the VLC icon, again, nothing happens. Any way to do this? Are there some hidden VLC and Flamesnot files that need to be removed? If so, how to do this?

Comment: What happens if you start VLC from the `terminal`? Show me any error messages. Try this... Log into a different user account (create one if you need to for testing purposes) and see if VLC works from there. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your shoes, and I have been, I'd uninstall and purge the config files then reinstall.
In a terminal:

```
sudo apt purge vlc
sudo apt install vlc
```

If that doesn't do the trick, I've found that nvidia 470 drivers are causing some very strange issues across the board.  I don't know if you have an nvidia card installed, but if you do, I'd revert to something earlier.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Issue Resolved.
I got it working. I took a deep breath and did my first Timeshift system restore and it worked! Flameshot and KDEConnect started working again, but my VLC snap was not working. I then removed the VLC snap and installed the VLC flatpak and that now is working normally. So I'm back to normal.
Thank goodness for Timeshift! Now I'll be doing system snapshots a lot more often (and properly commenting them).